# How can i draw a perpendicular line in a stream segment in a regular interval of 30m?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcgis-desktop, dynamic-segmentation

I have a stream segment which is polyline feature. Now I want to draw a line which is perpendicular to stream segment at a interval of 30m. How can i do it using python ? Do you have idea on this .

Comment: If you are using GIS software can you let us know which product(s) so that we can phrase a suitable answer, please?  Most GIS software will have their dynamic segmentation (sometimes known as linear referencing or chainage) capabilities documented.

Comment: I am using ArcMap10

Comment: The code in the accepted answer to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50108/elevation-profile-10-km-each-side-of-a-line/50841#50841) may be of interest.

Comment: Possibly a useful solution:http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/50841/8104

Comment: Isn't it possible without using other module. I need to use it in Arc Map 10.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not done so yet read up on [**route hatching**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00390000001n000000). Then you should be able to author a layer file with appropriate route hatching that you can use to add/update a layer using ArcPy.

Comment: +1 For dusting off one of the more obscure tricks in the hat