# Varying distance cross section along the river

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cross-section

I have used the script to draw the profile with this [gis.stackexchange.com/a/50841/8104.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50108/elevation-profile-10-km-each-side-of-a-line/50841#50841) This script is perfect.

Can you provide me with an idea, if in my case spacing is not same?

I have points with different spacing. I want to use those points instead of fixed spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be the US Army Corps of Engineers [HEC-GeoRAS tools for Arc](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-georas/). Though it comes with a lot of other stuff for building a HEC-RAS hydraulic model from GIS data, I remember that it had a pretty robust tool for creating cross-sections. However, I'd do some research in to it first to see if it will give you what you are looking for (irregular spacing).