# Extracting mountain peaks from a DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I want to find and extract the location and height of the highest 500 mountain peaks in a given area.
I was thinking to use NASADEM dataset and QGIS, but I did not find any working tools.

I am an intermediate user of QGIS and I just need to know if there are any tools or any calculation over the DEM that I can do.

Comment: Have you read that : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77609/how-to-extract-mountain-peak-points-from-a-given-digital-elevation-model

Comment: What is your definition of a peak?  Is there a minimum height above something like sea level, however defined?  Is there a minimum prominence above the col/low point of any connecting ridge?  Is there a minimum separating distance between peaks?

Comment: See the Convergence Index tool in SAGA  or GRASS (QGIS add on in processing tools) after you have addressed @johns question.  https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7/raster/r.convergence/r.convergence.html

Comment: Also this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79801/calculating-peaks-in-dem-using-grass